# Less CSS did not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Here is code:

styles.less:

```css
@background:red;
h1{
background:@background;
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Less</title>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="styles.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Bangladesh</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

---

I add this code in my project. Create two files which name is index.html and other styles.less.
I add less js files via googlecode.

I try to maximum time but did not work once time.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: Sorry for this miss..

Comment: actually less css does not work in my PC. what can i do now ? please help

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: You have to compile less css to css http://lesscss.org/

Comment: @LKG no you don't http://plungjan.name/SO/less.html - he just has to use a CDN link that works

Comment: But not showing on my computer. Need to connect something else?

Comment: wow it's work in my computer. Google Chrome does not supports this file. Now i just open mozilla firefox. Now work's.

Comment: Thank You so much @mplungjan :)

Comment: Your code MUST run from a server since the less.js wants to read the styles file using AJAX and Chrome does not allow Ajax from file system

Comment: Ok. From now i will do it.

Answer (score 1):

That cdn doesn't seem to be working. Try ...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
```